# Include part of the recipe according to the role

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

I'm using nginx_vhost recipe to apply it to two different roles, let's say `frontend` and `web`. nginx_vhost recipe has following code on its template for `vhost.conf` file:

```
<% if @upstream %>
upstream <%= @name %> {
<% @servers.each do |server| -%>
   server <%= server %> fail_timeout=0;
<% end -%>
<% @sockets.each do |socket| -%>
   server <%= socket %> fail_timeout=0;
<% end -%>
}
<% end %>
```

The code above will write:

```
upstream app_myproject.com {
   server unix:/www/myproject.com/control/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```

The problem is: I just need this on `frontend` role but not in `web` role. I was thinking to include it in the override_attributes section of `frontend` role but I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that it provides a new resource named `nginx_vhost` from [nginx_vhost](https://github.com/bbg-cookbooks/nginx_vhost) cookbook, it's supposed to be used into your custom recipes like this:

```
# foo::frontend
nginx_vhost "app_myproject.com" do
  sockets [ "unix:/www/myproject.com/control/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock" ]
end
```

You can define another resource for the recipe used in your role *web*:

```
# foo:web
nginx_vhost "web.myproject.com" do
  port 80
  stream false  # results no stream section in vhost config
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It gave me some pointers to solve the problem.